# phpMailer Attachment not working

Tags: php, attachment, phpmailer, contacts, contact-form

this is my first post and I hope that I can get some help regarding adding an attachment field in my phpMailer contact form. I have already added an uploader [browse] bar in the html website but I don't know how to link it with the phpmailer. do I have to declare it at the package which is phpmailer.php or do something with it?

I would really appreciate some help. Below is my desperate attempt.

Snippet from the code:

```
<?
$body = ob_get_contents();

$to = 'xxx@xxxx.com>';
$email = $email;
$subject = $subject;
$fromaddress = "xxx@xxxx.com";
$fromname = "Online Contact";

require("phpmailer.php"); //<<this is the original pack

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->From     = "xxx@xxxx.com";
$mail->FromName = "My Name";
$mail->AddBCC("xxx@xxxx.com","Name 1");
$mail->AddAddress( $email,"Name 2");

$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject  =  $subject;
$mail->Body     =  $body;
$mail->AltBody  =  "This is the text-only body";
// attachment
$mail->AddAttachment('uploadbar', 'new_file.pdf'); // the name of my html uploader is uploadbar, clicking browse to locate a file

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    $recipient = 'xxx@xxxx.com';
    $subject = 'Contact form failed';
    $content = $body;   

  mail($recipient, $subject, $content, "From: xxx@xxxx.com\r\nReply-To: $email\r\nX-Mailer: DT_formmail");
  exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 8):

Had the same problem, try this

```
$mail->AddAttachment($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/file-name.pdf');
```

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure your upload form has `enctype='multipart/form-data'` as in `<form method=post action=file.php enctype='multipart/form-data'>`.

then, use this code in your phpmailer handler file

```
foreach(array_keys($_FILES['files']['name']) as $key) {
   $source = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
   $filename = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];

   $mail->AddAttachment($source, $filename);
}
```

Comment: I replaced my AddAttachment line with all your lines. I still don't get any attachments in the email.

Comment: here is the phpmailer.php which I did not include any of its code - http://www.2shared.com/file/RcD8xdI1/phpmailer.html - What's included in my first post is the process.php

Comment: in your specific case, if upload input is named `uploadbar` use `$_FILES['uploadbar']` instead of `$_FILES['files']`

Comment: still not working. I don't know if you need more information to help you or files? Thank you by the way!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure attachment file name should not contain any special character and check the file path also correct.

> eg: [file name.pdf] Should be like [filename.pdf]