# Sendgrid PHP / PHPMailer - Attachment not adding to email

Tags: php, phpmailer, sendgrid

I use the below code to GET and upload my file input file to server location. I have no errors however the attachment is not adding to the email upon send?

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<input type="file" name="fileinput_name" id="fileinput_name"/>
```

PHP

```
if (array_key_exists('fileinput_name', $_FILES))
      {

        $uploadfile = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileinput_name"]["tmp_name"],"uploadtmp/" . $_FILES["fileinput_name"]["name"]);

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileinput_name']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
           // Attach the uploaded file
            $fileinputname = "uploadtmp/" . $_FILES["fileinput_name"]["name"];
            $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $fileinputname);

        }
      }
```

Mail sends with success and no errors in PHP Log.

Also, would be great if someone has a method to DELETE the file after mailsend OR a way I can achieve this without uploading to server at all?

I have tried these marked Answers however, still not able to attach to mail:

[phpMailer Attachment not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569586/phpmailer-attachment-not-working)

Comment: Both those are in place already

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add attachment through PHPMailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776126/add-attachment-through-phpmailer)

Comment: No, I have tried that. Including your previous answer, the attachment isn't attaching to the email. 

The attachment filename parameter is required.","field":"attachments.1.filename",

Thats the error I get when I do this: 

$teammail->addAttachment($_FILES["fileinput_name"]["tmp_name"] , $_FILES["fileinput_name"]["name"]);

Comment: Post a minimal reproducible example (submission form and PHP),  not just a fragment of your code, please